Installing a game with Windows 10 user A fails to create shortcuts accessible from other users B or C
After installing a game (Zenless Zone Zero) at the root of C:, I realise other users on my Windows 10 machine have none of the shortcuts (in start menu, desktop icon, etc) created during the installation. Is it because I should have installed it in Program Files?
Is there anything I can do to create these shortcuts?

Are you truly installing the game to the root of the drive? If so, don't. Program Files is where applications should be installed.

Start Menu Shortcuts are located in two folders:

%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs contains shortcuts viewable by all users
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs contains user specific shortcuts

Therefore you need to create a shortcut in the first location for it to be available for all users.
Desktop shortcuts, however are only located under %userprofile%\desktop, which is unique for every user, and thusm you'll manually need to create a copy of shortcut for all the users on your computer. 
As mentioned by Daniel B., a desktop common to all users also exist. To add an all user desktop icon, make a shortut in C:\Users\Public\Desktop

An all-users Desktop exists, too. It works just the same. Check this Q/A.

Thanks, it does answer my question. But as a side note I still can't launch the game from user B's desktop by clicking the new public icon: clicking the icon does successfully execute the game launcher program but for some reason the program doesn't seem to see the game as installed and shows a "Get Game" button. Whereas clicking the same icon from user A (the one who installed the game), the same button in the same game launcher program shows "Start the Game" instead. I don't get it, any idea what's wrong?

@drake035 does your game uses a game launcher? if so its possible that the launcher was installed in the root directory but the game, however, was installed only for the user. Right click on the shortcut for the game and open properties to check where the shortcut is actually pointing to. It seems that you mistakenly did a user installation instead of installing it for all users.

Oh no I had just mixed things up (kinda hard to explain what I did and not super interesting). All good now, thanks again :)
